# Pass CSS property as argument to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, css

I have a few nearly identical CSS animation functions for a JavaScript "class". The one I am posting below is for height, but I also have some for width, left, etc. It seems fairly redundant to me to have different functions for what is basically the same task, can I replace height in the function below with some kind of CSS property argument?

```
WindowItem.prototype.animateHeight = function(inElement, inTarget) {
    var selfCall = true;
    var currHeight = parseInt(inElement.style.height, 10);

    if (this.isExpanded) {
        if (currHeight < inTarget) {
            currHeight += ((inTarget-currHeight)>>3)+1;
            if (currHeight >= inTarget) {
                currHeight = inTarget;
                selfCall = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (currHeight > inTarget) {
            currHeight -= ((currHeight-inTarget)>>3)+1;
            if (currHeight <= inTarget) {
                currHeight = inTarget;
                selfCall = false;
            }
        }
    }
    inElement.style.height = currHeight+"px";

    if (selfCall) {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.animateHeight(inElement, inTarget);
        }, 33);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I probably should have also posted how I am calling this, I am not sure what to be passing the function to specify height in this example: `this.animateHeight(this.imgWindow, 0);`

Comment: `cssProperty="height"` and `inElement.style[cssProperty]`?

Comment: I just edited my post, I don't quite understand what to do with your code, could you explain please?

Comment: if you want to use this one function for any property given, you can use a parameter `this.animateProperty(this.imgWindow, 0, "height");`, where `WindowItem.prototype.animateHeight = function(inElement, inTarget, cssProperty) ... ` that's what i meant. unless I misunderstood the question

Comment: @user2264587 Just write this as a short answer, so asimes can accept it and future visitors can benefit from this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I wrote in my comment:

if you want to use this one function for any property given, you can use a parameter

```
this.animateProperty(this.imgWindow, 0, "height");
```

where

```
WindowItem.prototype.animateHeight = function(inElement, inTarget, cssProperty)
...
```

and instead of

```
inElement.style.height
```

use

```
inElement.style[cssProperty]
```